# Relationship between the dotnet cli and the new vs2017 msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, csproj, dotnet-cli

With the move from `project.json` to the new `csproj` format introduced with VS2017, I'm struggling to understand the difference between the `dotnet` cli and the new `msbuild` and when to use one over the other.

1) To build a new `csproj` netstandard library from the command line, should I be calling the `dotnet` cli (for example `dotnet restore` `dotnet build`) or use `msbuild` (for example `msbuild ExampleNetstandard.sln`).

2) Also, my understanding is that there are two versions of `msbuild`, one built on the full framework and another targeting `dotnet core`. Is this correct? Should I always use the `dotnet version`

3) Is `dotnet cli` standalone or does it require `msbuild` to be installed?. For instance when you install the dotnet SDK does this install msbuild as well? If so is this different to the version that is installed with vs2017?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

### Questions

> 1. To build a new csproj netstandard library from the command line, should I be calling the dotnet cli (for example dotnet restore dotnet build) or use msbuild (for example msbuild ExampleNetstandard.sln).

Both do fine as currently `dotnet` is built on top of `msbuild`. So it's a matter of taste. You could also call msbuild tasks by using the dotnet CLI. (`dotnet msbuild <msbuild_arguments>`)

In the beginning, all the .NET core stuff was only in `dotnet` and not in `msbuild`. This was cumbersome as a lot of stuff that was already built on `msbuild` wasn't working well with `dotnet` out of the box (e.g. Xamarin). So they moved the stuff to `msbuild` and build `dotnet` on top of `msbuild`.

`dotnet` has some features that aren't in `msbuild`, like `dotnet new`. In my opinion, `dotnet` is easier to use than `msbuild`, so I prefer `dotnet`.

To make it more clear, I have added a comparison between `msbuild` and `dotnet` at the end of my post.

> 2. Also, my understanding is that there are two versions of msbuild, one built on the full framework and another targeting dotnet core. Is this correct? Should I always use the dotnet version

There is only one msbuild. dotnet CLI is using msbuild:

> Since CLI uses MSBuild as its build engine, we recommend that these parts of the tool be written as custom MSBuild targets and tasks, since they can then take part in the overall build process

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/extensibility

The older version of `msbuild` was lacking the .NET Core support. Maybe that's the other version ;)

I agree it's confusing, as it was very different a few months ago.

> 3. Is dotnet cli standalone or does it require msbuild to be installed?. For instance when you install the dotnet SDK does this install msbuild as well? If so is this different to the version that is installed with vs2017?

I wasn't sure about this, but it was easy to test. I have removed all msbuild.exe and it still worked. Found out it's using the msbuild.dll in the SDK folder.
e.g. "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.3\MSBuild.dll"

If you remove that one, there is a proof:

[image: When msbuild.dll removed]

msbuild.dll is actually msbuild.exe, as you can see in the properties:

[image: msbuild.dll properties of SDK 1.0.3]

### Some code

If you look into the code of the dotnet CLI, you can see it's generating `msbuild` commands.

For example `dotnet restore`, is created by the [`RestoreCommand` class inside dotnet CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/0eff67d20768cff90eb125ff0e16e52cfc40ced6/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-restore/Program.cs).

A stripped version:

```cs
public class RestoreCommand : MSBuildForwardingApp
{
    ...
    public static RestoreCommand FromArgs(string[] args, string msbuildPath = null)
    {
        var result = parser.ParseFrom("dotnet restore", args);
        ...
        var msbuildArgs = new List<string>
        {
            "/NoLogo",
            "/t:Restore",
            "/ConsoleLoggerParameters:Verbosity=Minimal"
        };
        ...
        return new RestoreCommand(msbuildArgs, msbuildPath);
    }

    public static int Run(string[] args)
    {
        RestoreCommand cmd;
        try
        {
            cmd = FromArgs(args);
        }
        catch (CommandCreationException e)
        {
            return e.ExitCode;
        }
        
        return cmd.Execute();
    }
    ...
}
```

You can see `dotnet restore` is just calling `msbuild /NoLogo /t:Restore /ConsoleLoggerParameters:Verbosity=Minimal`

---

If you check [`RestoreCommand` in the time of `dotnet v1.0.0 RC2`](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/6cde21225e18fc48eeab3f4345ece3e6bb122e53/src/dotnet/commands/dotnet-restore/Program.cs#L36), it wasn't using `msbuild` but was calling `nuget` directly.

```
return NuGet3.Restore(args, quiet);
```

### Mapping between `dotnet` and `msbuild`

I made a mapping between `dotnet` and `msbuild`. It's not complete, but the important commands are there.

```
Dotnet                 | Msbuild                                    | Remarks                         
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------------------------
Add                    |                                            |         
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------------------------                        
Build                  | /t:Build                                   |  
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------------------------                                
Build --no-incremental | /t:Rebuild                                 |    
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|---------------------------------                              
Clean                  | /t:clean                                   |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Complete               |                                            |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Help                   |                                            | Help!                           
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
List                   |                                            |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Migrate                | -                                          |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Msbuild                |                                            | Forwarding all                  
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
New                    |                                            |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Nuget                  |                                            |  *
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Pack                   | /t:pack                                    |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Publish                | /t:publish                                 |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Remove                 |                                            |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Restore                | /NoLogo /t:Restore                         |
                       | /ConsoleLoggerParameters:Verbosity=Minimal |
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Run                    | /nologo /verbosity:quiet                   |
                       | /p:Configuration=   /p:TargetFramework     |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Sln                    |                                            | Not in msbuild                  
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Store                  | /t:ComposeStore                            |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Test                   | /t:VSTest /v:quiet /nologo                 |                                 
-----------------------|--------------------------------------------|--------------------------------- 
Vstest                 |                                            | Forwarding to vstest.console.dll
```

`*` dotnet nuget: Adding/removing packages to csproj, also limited set of nuget.exe, see [comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools#feature-availability)

PS [no markdown tables in SO :(](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables)

Comment: `msbuild` does not restore NuGet packages, so I don't think you can say "both do fine" without a little bit more context. Other parts look good.

Comment: `msbuild /t:restore` is the new restore. Showed it with code. It's new (as before `dotnet` was **not** using msbuild)

Comment: Great answer.. I just have one more question (I have updated the original question). If you could answer that I would much appreciate it and will accept your answer

Comment: Good question. I wasn't sure and tested it. Conclusion: it uses it's own msbuild.dll. Updated the post.