# Difference between .NetCore, VisualStudio build and MSBuild task in Azure Pipeline?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm creating a new CI Azure Pipeline for my .Net Core projects. In Azure pipeline, Microsoft has provided three task for build i.e., .Net Core, Visual Studio Build and MSBuild.

Since all three task does build operation, do we have any specific criteria to choose one task over another?

I've gone through the documentation provided by Microsoft but I couldn't find much detail on this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops

**Edit**
Note: I'm aware that Visual Studio build task has a versioning sub task, but this can be achieved by separate custom task as well.

Comment: You say the project is .Net Core, Microsoft provide .Net Core task, so why use other tasks?

Comment: The other tasks can also be used to build the .Net Core projects. Is there any guideline provided by Microsoft why to use it over the other two tasks?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Difference between .NetCore, VisualStudio build and MSBuild task in Azure Pipeline?

As we know, `dotnet` is built on top of `msbuild`, we could call `msbuild tasks` by using the `dotnet CLI`.

That is the reason why you can use `MSBuild task` or `.Net Core task` to build your project/solution.

Assuredly, `dotnet` has some features that aren't in `msbuild`, like `dotnet new`. At this point, `dotnet` is easier to use than `msbuild`.

But, if we build some `.net` projects (not `.net core`), we just need use `MSBuild task` instead of `.NET Core task`. Because we do not need install unnecessary `dotnet SDK`.

So, when we building the project/solution without special needs, the `.net core task` and the `msbuild task` are just a matter of taste.

On the other hand, `MSBuild` is part of Visual Studio, when we build the project/solution with Visual Studio, it will invoke the `MSBuild` to execute some build task to complete the build project/solution.

Sometimes we do not want to install the full Visual Studio on our build server just to build our project/solution, in this case, we could use the `MSBuild task`  to build the project/solution on the server instead of installing the full Visual Studio.

So in a nutshell, `dotnet` is built on top of `msbuild` and `MSBuild` is part of Visual Studio, that is the reason why you can use MSBuild and Visual Studio to build .net core project.

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422488/relationship-between-the-dotnet-cli-and-the-new-vs2017-msbuild) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Being not so rigorous, I can say that dotnet contains msbuild, and msbuild contains nuget. So as you can pack packages with msbuild, you can also build projects with dotnet.

Comment: Poor answer not focused on the question

Answer (score 0):

nb the VSBuild task will only run on a Windows agent machine, so if you want builds to run on linux then the DotNetCoreCLI task is your simplest option.